# Load an .exe file and make it run on startup on every pc

Tags: vb.net

I made a [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) application that can load an .exe application. I want an application (from which I haven't got the source code) to load on startup on multiple computers. Below you can see a little of my code.

Comment: perhaps something *is* happening and you dont know because you are swallowing the exception

Comment: The application isn't in msconfig on my other pc. I will try to run it again :)

Comment: 2 things to note, that might help you: 1-you are adding the key to Current User, not any user that logs on to the computer. 2-you are adding under 'run' which will occur the next time the 'Current User' logs in, not right now and not on 'startup'.

Comment: Show the exception. Might be UAC related.

Comment: Yes i will edit it to HKLM thanks. I thought Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run is the place where all the startup programs are stored in windows.

Comment: Have you already tried to use a builder and a stub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make two projects:

1. A builder
2. A Stub

Most crypters use this method, search it on the www.

Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21cnPy5Pejo

Answer (score 0):

You probably are hiding the execution error message. You can show it like this:

```
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
```

Comment: No, the code is working fine. Tried this already. The only way i can put an other exe in startup is making a kind of "stub". But this is completely new for me...